# Laravel Nova: bypass accessor to getOriginal

Tags: resources, laravel-nova

When using Laravel Nova you may expect `$this->getOriginal('name')` to bypass an accessor to return the database value of name. However, this is not the case.

```
Text::make('Name')
    ->resolveUsing(function(){
        return $this->getOriginal('name')
    });

// Returns value provided by accessor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the actual original property use getRawOriginal()

```
Text::make('Name')
    ->resolveUsing(function(){
        return $this->getRawOriginal('name')
    });

// Returns value from database
```

Comment: In my case, it is not working as it should. If I have accessor for name then it uses it. So what I did is Text::make('Customer Name') ->resolveUsing(function(){ return $this->getRawOriginal('name')});
and add a mutator for CustomerName to set name. While getting it by passes accessor and while setting it used mutator.